# SSRS Report: Issue with repeating headers

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I put some repeating headers but when the browser display the report directly it looks all messed up, but if I select to save the report as PDF the reports looks like I want.

[image: From Browser]

[image: When saved as PDF]

Comment: how i can fix the web browser view

Comment: Have you tried putting each matrix in a seperate rectangle ?

Comment: No, i will try that and post my results back